# Pandas: blank bar plot using logy=True

Tags: pandas, plot

When creating a bar plot from a Pandas DataFrame, the canvas is coming out blank (i.e., no bars showing). Tried in two different computers running the same Pandas version (v0.20.3), one will work and the other won't. This code reproduces the problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {0: {0: 15.966058232618138,
     1: 2.1807683719000992,
     2: 0.87035229502695233,
     3: 0.34367909767875798,
     4: 0.18218519090896321},
 1: {0: 11.118024492865494,
     1: 0.69351230042284107,
     2: 0.43197780592175244,
     3: 0.076875254138056778,
     4: 0.090691059750999822},
 2: {0: 10.59611816777141,
     1: 1.0043841242178624,
     2: 0.66999680161427466,
     3: 0.032357377554541628,
     4: 0.18821105178736078},
 3: {0: 0.19480519480519479,
     1: 17.036783213824904,
     2: 5.2625018367047067,
     3: 1.5041249436616959,
     4: 0.14895013123359582},
 4: {0: 0.86666666666666659,
     1: 53.71924947880472,
     2: 99.890829694323145,
     3: 10.031712688463491,
     4: 4.6052631578947372},
 5: {0: 1.8914728682170541,
     1: 3554.8711656441715,
     2: 573.03649635036504,
     3: 0.72058823529411753,
     4: 0.93846153846153835},
 6: {0: 3.8978637334734652,
     1: 0.19517839782493598,
     2: 0.14753506501156222,
     3: 0.021084786319386508,
     4: 0.029238890916504161},
 7: {0: 4.7377049180327866,
     1: 0.056476683937823832,
     2: 0.034086444007858548,
     3: 0.99022801302931596,
     4: 0.92809364548494977},
 8: {0: 0.0058997050147492625,
     1: 0.0,
     2: 0.0,
     3: 1.2954206878683853e-05,
     4: 0.025023084025854108},
 9: {0: 0.041333014548300184,
     1: 0.23146322426025379,
     2: 0.11579453571122432,
     3: 0.3291825442962299,
     4: 0.022578918480011249}} )
df.plot.bar( logy=True )
```

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: As I said: "The canvas is coming out blank (i.e., no bars showing)."

Comment: what are the differences between the two computers?

Comment: From the software both are running Arch Linux with Python 2.7.14 and Pandas 0.20.3. The main difference I can think can be the culprit is that the one which works is running Matplotlib 2.0.2, while the one which does not runs on Matplotlib  2.1.0. Upgrading Matplotlib to see if it breaks is not an option, as I need to be able to plot this and I won't be able to downgrade later (as Arch Linux is a rolling distribution).

Comment: +1: I have the same problem.  `df.plot(logy=True)` works fine, but not `df.plot(kind='bar', logy=True)` which comes out completely blank. BTW it's not the zeros in there, `(1+df).plot(kind='bar', logy=True)` also comes out blank. Using python: 3.6.4, pandas: 0.23.1, matplotlib: 2.1.0.

Comment: **After update to python: 3.6.6, pandas: 0.23.1, matplotlib: 2.2.2 it now works fine.**

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Trying to replicate the issue. The plot is shown above